# Image Not getting saved in folder PHP

Tags: php, android

I am trying to save the profile image to the image folder but When i click save button it says that "Uploaded File is not a valid image, Image type is not supported,Unable to upload image to server" It doesnot show any error in the logcat. Please Help.

This is my Upload.php

```
    <?php
      $target_dir = "images/";
   $target_file = $target_dir . time()."-".basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
   $uploadOk = 1;
   $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
   $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
   
   $response = array();
   $error = "";
   
   
   
   if($check != false){
       $uploadOK = 0;
         $error .= "Uploaded File is not a valid image. ";
      
   }else{
       $uploadOK = 1;
     
   }
   
   if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType  !=  "png" && $imageFileType  !=  "jpeg" && $imageFileType  !=  "gif")
   {
       $uploadOK = 1;
     
   }else{
       $uploadOK = 0;
       $error .= "Image type is not supported";
   }
   
   if($uploadOK == 0)
   {
       $response['status'] = 0;
       $response['message'] = $error; 
   }else{
       if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){
           $userId =  $_POST['userId'];
           $response['status'] = 1;
           $response['message'] = "Image Uploaded Successfully!";
       }else{
           $response['status'] = 0;
           $response['message'] = "Unable to upload image to server";
       }
   }
   echo json_encode($response);
   
   
   ?>
```

Comment: Try adding more parentheses in your if-clause: `if (($imageFileType != "jpg") && ($imageFileType  !=  "png") && ($imageFileType  !=  "jpeg") && ($imageFileType  !=  "gif"))`... and swap the then/else parts

Comment: `"Uploaded File is not a valid image` That is your own message and does not tell much. Better tell what went wrong.